# Washington State tax filing extension?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, extension

I just filed a federal tax-filing-deadline extension for myself.

Does Washington state require a separate one?

Turbo Tax didn't mention anything about it (I used it to file my extension) and it wasn't one of the states on their list of states with specific extension instructions.

Comment: What state tax(es) are you asking about?  Washington State has a "Business & Occupation tax", a "sales tax", "workers' compensation insurance", "unemployment insurance", and a real estate transfer tax, but does not have an "income tax".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Washington State doesn't have a state income tax for individuals, so unless you've got a business there's nothing to file. [Find out more on their website.](http://dor.wa.gov/content/findtaxesandrates/incometax/)